# Can't view the movement of my javascript animation?

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

So I'm trying to do some simple javascript animation with an image, and this is as far as I've gotten. I can load the file, but it simply shows the 'end result' and no actual movement (unless I step through each movement with console). I'm pretty sure I need to use setTimeout somewhere in my code, but can't seem to find the right way to use it.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img;    
img = new Image();
img.src = "img/background4x3.png";

var sun;    
sun = new Image();
sun.src = "img/rsz_sun_200x200.png";
var y = 250;

var func1 = function (y) {

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 500);
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 600, 500);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
setTimeout(100000);
ctx.drawImage(sun, 5, y);

};

img.onload = function() {
 //x = 1;
 while(y > 150) {
     func1(y);
     y = y - 5;
     setTimeout(100000);
    }       
};
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a correct usage of `setTimeout`. It doesn't "sleep" for this time. The script just runs a function after some time. Please, read [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) before using.

```
setTimeout(myFunction, 1000); // runs myFunction after a second
```

In your case, there are several ways to do this properly. For example, you can use `setInterval`. Just something like this:

```
var y = 250, interval;

var func1 = function () {    
    if (y < 150) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        return;
    }

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 500);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 600, 500);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    ctx.drawImage(sun, 5, y);    

    y = y - 5;
};

img.onload = function() {
    func1();
    interval = setInterval(func1, 10000);
};
```

or using `setTimeout` in another way:

```
var y = 250, interval;

var func1 = function () {    
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 500);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 600, 500);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    ctx.drawImage(sun, 5, y);    

    y = y - 5;
    if (y > 150) {
        setTimeout(func1, 1000);
    }
};

img.onload = function() {
    func1();
};
```